# LibGDX. Box2d. Joint. Вращение соединённых тел или танк и башня

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Всем привет. Пытаюсь в LibGDX посредствам Box2d реализовать танк с башней.

Шасси:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.bullet = true;

PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(sizeM.x / 2, sizeM.y / 2);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = MASS / (sizeM.x * sizeM.y);

Body body = world.createBody(bodyDefComponent.bodyDef);
body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(this);

body.setLinearDamping(DAMPING);
body.setAngularDamping(DAMPING);
```

Башня:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.bullet = true;
bodyDef.angularDamping = 3;

PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(sizeM.x / 2, sizeM.y / 2);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = MASS / (sizeM.x * sizeM.y);

Body body = world.createBody(bodyDefComponent.bodyDef);
body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(this);
```

Соединение (Joint):

```
RevoluteJointDef jointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
jointDef.enableMotor = true;
jointDef.maxMotorTorque = 10000;
jointDef.initialize(mChassis, mTower, new Vector2(position.x, position.y));
Joint joint = world.createJoint(jointDef);
```

Поворот башни делаю так:

```
body.applyAngularImpulse(-ROTATION_POWER, true);
```

Поведение должно быть, как у танка, то есть при повороте шасси вращается башня, при вращении башни, башня вращается относительно шасси, при этом шасси не вращается. Пока получается, что при повороте башни, вращается и шасси. Пробовал экспериментировать с angularDamping и density - не помогло. Вращается даже с бесконечной массой. Есть подозрение, что что-то не так с соединением.